# How do I prevent focus change if an entry is invalid?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want if one field has invalid entry, message to be displayed on moving out of that field and focus should remain on that field.  But in following code validation of next field is also triggered when moving out of first field.  I have commented set focus, otherwise, it gets into an infinite loop.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox

root = Tk()

def callback1():
    if (len(e1.get()) <4):
        messagebox.showinfo("error", "Field 1 length < 4")
        #e1.focus_set()
        return False
    else:
        return True
    
def callback2():
    if (len(e2.get()) <4):
        messagebox.showinfo("error", "Field 2 length < 4")
        #e2.focus_set()
        return False
    else:
        return True

e1 = Entry(root, validate="focusout", validatecommand=callback1)
e1.grid()
e2 = Entry(root,  validate="focusout", validatecommand=callback2)
e2.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You might want to rethink your strategy.  Nothing makes a person madder than having to fight their computer for control.

Comment: If your question has been solved, do consider upvoting and marking the answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This indicates to the wider StackOverflow community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1):

When you place your cursor in `e1`, type something which does not satisfy the `validatecommand` condition and then try to place your cursor in `e2`, the following sequence of events takes place:

1. `e1` loses focus and calls `callback1`
2. Meanwhile, the cursor is placed in `e2` and `e2` gets focus
3. The msgbox window for `e1` takes focus and is ready to pop up just when...
4. `e2` loses focus and calls `callback2`
5. The msgbox window for `e2` pops up
6. This is followed by the pop up for `e1` which was waiting in the queue

The root cause for the problem is that the messagebox window takes focus, which in turn triggers the other entry box. This approach seems to be highly fragile due to the strong interplay of events.

Notice that if you just print the information to the terminal, everything works perfectly as the terminal doesn't take focus.

So, I would recommend you display the information using an alternate method where the widget showing the information won't steal focus. One option is to display the information using a label.

---

Now coming to your second problem, if you want the entry to retain focus if the entered text is not valid, you could use a global variable (`hanging`) to keep track of whether the user is in the *process* of filling an entry successfully.

If the user is in the process of filling an entry, he/she will not be able to place the cursor in the other entry because `FocusIn1` and `FocusIn2` return "break" when `hanging` equals True.

You can replace the print statements in the below working code using a label.

---

### Working Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox

root = Tk()
hanging = False #True implies that the user is in the process of filling an entry successfully

def onFocusOut1():
   global hanging
   hanging = True
   if (len(e1.get()) <4):
       print("error", "Field 1 length < 4")
       e1.focus_set()
       return False
   else:
      hanging = False
      return True
    
def onFocusOut2():
   global hanging
   hanging = True
   if (len(e2.get()) <4):
       print("error", "Field 2 length < 4")
       e2.focus_set()
       return False
   else:
       hanging = False
       return True

def onFocusIn1():
    if hanging:
       return "break"
    e1.configure(validate="focusout", validatecommand=onFocusOut1)

def onFocusIn2():
    if hanging:
       return "break"
    e2.configure(validate="focusout", validatecommand=onFocusOut2)

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.grid()
e2 = Entry(root)
e2.grid()

#Binding both the entries to FocusIn
e1.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: onFocusIn1())
e2.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: onFocusIn2())

root.mainloop()
```

PS: It turns out that you can actually use `messagebox.showinfo` itself in place of `print` in the working code. The first problem got solved automatically along with the second one. So, this gives the *complete* solution to your problem.

Comment: That's good advice, but it still doesn't address the problem where the second entry takes focus from the first. The OP said _"If one field has invalid entry [...] focus should remain on that field."_

Comment: Suggested solution of adding label works fine to prevent validation of next field but as soon as tried to set focus on field having error, it still goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I have now updated my answer and added a solution to make an entry retain focus if the entered input in invalid.

Comment: @AmanKhanna Does the edited answer solve your problem? Feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

Comment: Yes, it fixed my issue. Thanks

Comment: @Sriram Srinivasan, In a multi window environment if from an entry widget having non-valid entry I click to open a new window, application goes into am infinite loop.